# D3js collapsible tree gives out error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I m implementing d3 collapsible tree into my angular js application. Everything was going fine at first and the console did show any error. After changing several attributes in the code below, the console logs the error

`Invalid value for <g> attribute transform="translate(undefined,undefined)`

So I changed the code back to the initial state, however, the error keep showing up. I googled the problem and it was due to "d.x and d.y is undefined sometimes".
But I did not any problem as all the data are included in the js file and not being retrieved remotely.

Thank you

```
function buildVerticalTree(treeData,treeContainerDom){

  var margin = {top :40,right:120,bottom:20,left:120};
  var width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left;
  var height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var i = 0, duration = 750;
  var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height,width]);

  var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d){
      return [d.x, d.y];
    });

  var svg = d3.select(treeContainerDom).append("svg")
    .attr("width",width+margin.left+margin.right)
    .attr("height",height+margin.top+margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform","translate("+margin.left+","+margin.top+")");

  var root = treeData;
  update(root);

  function update(source){
    var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse();
    var links = tree.links(nodes);

    nodes.forEach(function(d){
      d.y = d.depth * 100;
    });

    var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes,function(d){
        return d.id || (d.id=++i);
      });

    var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class","node")
      .attr("transform",function(d){
        return "translate("+source.x0+","+source.y0+")";
      }).on("click",nodeclick);

    nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r",10)
      .attr("stroke",function(d){
        return d.children || d._children ? "steelblue" : "#00c13f";
      })
      .style("fill",function(d){
        return d.children || d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
      });

    nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("y",function(d){
        return d.children || d._children ? -18 : 18;
      })
      .attr("dy",".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor","middle")
      .text(function(d){
        return d.name;
      })
      .style("fill","black")
      .style("fill-opacity",1e-6);

    var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform",function(d){
        return "translate("+ d.x+","+ d.y+")";
      });

    nodeUpdate.select("circle")
      .attr("r",10)
      .style("fill",function(d){
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
      });

    nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity",1);

    var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform",function(d){
        return "translate("+source.x+","+source.y+")";
      })
      .remove();

    nodeExit.select("circle")
      .attr("r",1e-6);

    nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity",1e-6);

    var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links,function(d){
        return d.target.id;
      });

    link.enter().insert("path","g")
      .attr("class","link")
      .attr("d",function(d){
        var o = {x:source.x0,y:source.y0};
        return diagonal({source:o,target:o});
      });
    link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d",diagonal);

    link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d",function(d){
        var o = {x:source.x,y:source.y};
        return diagonal({source:o,target:o});
      })
      .remove();

    nodes.forEach(function(d){
      d.x0 = d.x;
      d.y0 = d.y;
    });
  }

  function nodeclick(d){

    if(d.children){
      d._children = d.children;
      d.children = null;
    }else{
      d.children = d._children;
      d._children = null;
    }
    update(d);
  }

}

var treeData =
{
  "name": "BU Head",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Manager",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Team Lead",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Team Lead",
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Manager",
      "children": []
    }
  ]
};

buildVerticalTree(treeData, "#tree");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors can be avoided by checking the source before passing to  diagonal function value:

```
  .attr("d",function(d){
    if(!source.x0 && !source.y0)
        return "";//return empty when source x0 and y0 is not available.
    var o = {x:source.x0,y:source.y0};
    return diagonal({source:o,target:o});
  });
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ep94zfso/)